# How to create an array of arrays in C when the number of subarrays is not specified?

Tags: arrays, c

I am trying to create an array of arrays but the the number of subarrays is unknown.

Comment: Use `malloc` for the array and you can use `realloc` to enlarge it. for ints for example declare as `int **myArrays;`

Comment: You can generally use `malloc` to create such 'jagged' arrays. But more details and clarity in your question would help to get a specific answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I declare a 2d array in C++ using new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new)

Comment: Are all the subarrays the same length? If so, the array can be easily defined as a single variable length array, or allocated as a single,  dynamically allocated block (using `malloc` or `calloc`) rather than as an array of pointers to the first elements of different length subarrays (which would be 'jagged').

Comment: @DevUt note that `new` and `delete` are C++ operators, while OP asks about C

Comment: This question is a bit minimalistic. Which made me tend to answer: "What you do not know, you do not need."

Answer (score 1):

Jagged array is array of arrays such that member arrays can be of different sizes, i.e., we can create a 2-D array but with a variable number of columns in each row.

**Static Jagged Array**:

```
int kk0[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };  
int kk1[2] = { 5, 6 }; 
int* jagged[2] = { kk0, kk1 };
```

**Dynamic Jagged Array**:

```
 int* jagged[2]; 
 jagged[0] = malloc(sizeof(int) * 1); 
 jagged[1] = malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);
```

Reference : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array

Comment: Better word: "*[A] jagged array can be accessed like an array of arrays ...*", because it explicitly is **not** an array of arrays, but a ... well ... "jagged" array.

Comment: Good, heard first time **Jagged**, but only problem is sequential access is not possible

Comment: Sorry I think this is not the one I am looking for

Comment: Also "jagged" arrays can be created to use exactly one continuous block of memory.

Answer (score 1):

> *"create an array of arrays but the the number of subarrays is unknown."*

If using `C99`, or a compiler since then that supports [variable length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (optional since C11), this would provide a way to do this at run-time.  A short example:

```
#define ARRAY_BASE_SIZE 20 //known at compile time

int main()
{
    int numSubArrays = 0; 
    printf("enter a value for number of sub-arrays:\n");
    int count = scanf("%d", &numSubArrays);//not known until run-time
    if(count == 1)
    {
        int array[ARRAY_BASE_SIZE][numSubArrays];
        memset(array, 0, sizeof(array)); 
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: VLAs are optional since C11. I know you probaly know, but well ...

Comment: @alk - Actually since C99 (which of course is older) , that's why I included the statement _"If using C99, or a compiler since then_ that supports _"_  But thanks .

Comment: Ahyes, well, fair enough. Still explicitly mentioning C99 then is either redundant or just half the truth. ;)

Comment: @Alk - I only do that as it is a common way to introduce [VLAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (look at the Implementation section).  But why do you say that it is redundant.  Do you not feel it is important to qualify the suggestion by limiting it to only a sub-set of compilers?  (I have always provided that disclaimer when mentioning VLA.)

Comment: up'ed. Still: "`sizeof ` is an operator not a function!" ;->

Comment: @Alk - Its been awhile since I've seen you around the C pages.  I forgot how much fun you can be.

Comment: Well, I felt as I tent to mostly pick on other peoples postings, I perhaps needed to turn to something completly new, put on the noob cap again, so I decide to dive into understanding and manoeuvering this kind of machines: https://www.mycloud.ch/l/P0084C2443AE29CB8EEC34CBE23C06E54F3551AE464C7677295E9C84C8AB1FB3A .... thousands of pages of new old documentation to read, knobs to to turn, button to switch, ... ;) Today I stumnbled in here more or less by .. well let's say accident. But to be honest it *is* fun being here ... again ;)

Comment: @alk - you are an off-roader!  Looks like tremendous fun.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of sub arrays is not known then the array must be expandable when there are more sub arrays than you thought.

```
int **myArrays;        // the array of arrays
int nSubArrays= 0;     // its current size
int nUsed= 0;          // how many have been used
#define INCREMENT 5    // increment for alocation

myArrays= malloc(sizeof(int *) * INCREMENT);
nSubArrays= INCREMENT;
nUsed= 0;
```

now fill the array(s):

```
myArrays[nUsed]= fillSubArray();
nUsed++;
```

and expand the array when it becomes full:

```
if (nUsed==nSubArrays) {
    int **tmp= realloc(myArrays, sizeof(int *)*(nSubArrays+INCREMENT));
    if (!tmp) return 0; // error
    myArrays= tmp;
    nSubArrays += INCREMENT;
```

Answer (score 0):

In C it is very common practice to declare a pointer and reference it as an array. In C an array will decay to a pointer when the reference of the array is assigned to the pointer. To reference an array of arrays, it is common to declare a pointer-to-pointer, assign it to the reference of a 2-D array, and later index it like a 2-D array.

The following are all equivalent. `argv` is an array of array of `char`. Using `[]` makes your intention of using indexing a pointer as an array clear to other programmers who might be reading your code.

```
char **argv;
char *argv[];
```

<s>char argv[][];</s>  (this is wrong)

The size of the array is usually communicated separately. In fact, the parameters of the `main` function does just that. When you see

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]);
```

The `char *argv[]` is an array of array of characters (aka array of strings) passed from the command line. The argument `argc` represents the number of arrays in  `argv`. To index the first element in the array, use `argv[0]`, whose type is will be `char*` (aka `char[]`).

Comment: believe this is a problem. `char argv[][];`

Comment: This shows how to declare them but not how to allocate.  See Paul's comment - you want to include `malloc` or `realloc`.

Comment: Yes `char argv[][]` is incorrect. I'll fix it

Answer (score 0):

How about this, its just an attempt to give a start point, not the complete answer, but we can build on this.

Also we need to keep track of `size` of each subarray to access valid locations, am sure that can be done easily by some kind of book keeping.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BASE_SIZE 3

int main()
{
    int** dyn_array = NULL;
    int countSubArray  = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int size = 0;
    
    dyn_array = malloc(sizeof (int* ) * BASE_SIZE);
    if ( dyn_array ) {
        printf("enter number of subarrays:");
        scanf("%d", &countSubArray);
        while( count < countSubArray) {
            printf("enter sizeof %d subarray", count+1);
            scanf("%d", &size);
            if ( dyn_array[count] = malloc(sizeof (int) * size) )
            {
                printf("Allocated sub array %d at %p\n",count+1, (void*) dyn_array[count]);
            }
            count++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```